# Is it possible to have an interface that has private / protected methods?

Tags: php, oop, interface

Is it possible in PHP 5 to have an interface that has private / protected methods?

Right now I have:

```
interface iService
{
    private method1();
}
```

That throws an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE

I just want to have confirmation that it is the case that an interface can only contain public methods.

Comment: I find the answer disappointing. I would like interfaces that support protected/private methods as well. For example, I have a class, where a public method, implemented in the abstract, relies on a protected method implemented by subclass. I want to use an interface to require subclasses to implement the protected methods required by the abstract public methods.

Comment: Use an abstract base class for that purpose. You can combine the two approaches: public methods in the interface, implementation of those methods in an abstract base class that defines (and relies on) abstract protected methods.

Comment: If you could declare private or protected methods, it would be `private function method1 ();` not `private method1();`.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

The [PHP manual page about interfaces](http://php.net/interface) explicitly states:

> All methods declared in an interface must be public; this is the nature of an interface.

I guess this explains the error you are getting ;-)

Answer (score 23):

Interfaces are used to describe public methods of a class implementing that interface. You can never have a private method in an interface. Any methods in an interface are assumed to be in use and should not be changed.

[Interfaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) is the PHP link, but this is standard in OO programming.

Comment: in other languages like java , you could use access modifiers in interfaces.

Answer (score 13):

In general an interface can only have public members, because the only function of an interface is to be inherited.

From PHPfreaks.com tutorial:

> PHP5 features interfaces. Not to be
>   confused with interfaces in the more
>   general sense, the interface keyword
>   creates an entity that can be used to
>   enforce a common interface upon
>   classes without having to extend them
>   like with abstract classes. Instead an
>   interface is implemented.
>
> Interfaces are different from abstract
>   classes. For one, they’re not actually
>   classes. They don’t define properties,
>   and they don’t define any behaviour.
>   The methods declared in an interface
>   must be declared in classes that
>   implement it.
>
> Because an interface in the more
>   general sense is a definition of how
>   an object interacts with other code,
>   all methods must be declared public
>   (see section on visibility in this
>   chapter). Using abstract classes, an
>   abstract method can have any
>   visibility, but the extending classes
>   must have their implementations use
>   the same (or weaker) visibility.
>   Implementing an interface adds the
>   methods as abstract methods to the
>   subject class, failure to implement it
>   will result in an error like the
>   following:
>
> Fatal error: Class SomeConcreteClass
>   contains n abstract method(s) and must
>   therefore be declared abstract or
>   implement the remaining methodsYes,
>   abstract classes can implement
>   interfaces.

Comment: It's too bad. Because I would like to have a public method, required by the interface, implemented in an abstract class, that relies on a protected method also enforced by the interface. This way, the abstract class can provide the public interface, but it's up to subclasses to implement the underlying logic. Make sense?

Comment: Seems like you want the method to be implemented by the subclass to be abstract. Then any subclass MUST implement it. But it has nothing to do with the interface.

Comment: @Stoutie Interface should not define supporting methods for abstract class implementation - that should be done by defining an abstract method on the abstract class

Answer (score 6):

interfaces are type declarations.  a type is set of values, plus a set of operations that can be carried upon them from outside.  a private method doesn't fit into this picture.

```
interface T {
  public /*int*/ function f(array $a);
}
interface U {
  public /*T*/ function g(T $t);
}

class C implements U {
    public function g(T $t) {
        ...
        $x = $t->f();
        ...
    }
}
```

interfaces are useful because they state, well, objects' interfaces.  how the objects communicate with their environment.

now let's say `T::f` could be declared private.  how would that be useful to other objects?  it would not callable from outside, it would not be part of its interface.

Comment: Agreed...
But it could be protected right?
As abstract classes allow...

Comment: @asdfasdfasdf I think you should have learned the right way since, but for others : protected methods can't be accessed from OUTSIDE the object/class.

So there's no reason a protected method could be defined in an interface, as it defines method for the object to be manipulated/accessed from outside.

Example :

In a MVC architecture, controllers ask view to render the page. 

To let everyone know something use the "render" method, you make all views implements an interface defining this method !

So when implementing new view, developer know directly they need to add this method.

Answer (score 4):

In many cases, an interface definition helps other modules guarantee the behavior and the API of a class. In those cases, private methods are not something the other modules can access or understand. That's why you can never put private methods on an interface.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, interfaces can only define the publicly visible methods. I wanted to show an example of how protected methods can be handled. To impose the use of specific protected methods, it is possible to create an abstract class that implements the interface.

This especially makes sense if the abstract class can already handle some of the workload, to simplify the actual implementation. Here for example, an abstract class takes care of instantiating the result object, which is always needed:

First off, the interface.

```php
interface iService
{
   /**
    * The method expects an instance of ServiceResult to be returned.
    * @return ServiceResult
    */
    public function doSomething();
}
```

The abstract class then defines the internal methods structure:

```php
abstract class AbstractService implements iService
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // prepare the result instance, so extending classes
        // do not have to do it manually themselves.
        $result = new ServiceResult();

        $this->process($result);

        return $result;
    }

   /**
    * Force all classes that extend this to implement
    * this method.
    *
    * @param ServiceResult $result
    */
    abstract protected function process($result);
}
```

The class that does the actual implementation automatically inherits the interface from the abstact class, and only needs to implement the protected method.

```php
class ExampleService extends AbstractService
{
    protected function process($result)
    {
         $result->setSuccess('All done');
    }
}
```

This way the interface fulfills the public contract, and through the `AbstractService` class, the internal contract is fulfilled. The application only needs to enforce the use of the `AbstractService` class wherever applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Big **NO**, any method in the Interface will never have private or protected access identifier.

**All methods declared in an interface must be public; this is the nature of an interface.

**Few other interesting facts about interface**

Interfaces can be extended like classes using the extends operator. They can extend only other interfaces. (source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

Note that it is possible to declare a constructor in an interface, which can be useful in some contexts, e.g. for use by factories. Signature should be same in the child class.

**In your case, even another problem is - function keyword is missing in the function declaration.** **It should be**

```
interface iService
{
    public function method1();
}
```